# Dell Inspiron 15 3000 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation, dell, amd-processor

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3000, it came with Ubuntu 12.04, I wanted to upgrade it to 14.04, but when I try to boot from USB, after I choose start from the menu (where there is install, check memory etc) all I get is a blinking cursor on black background. This is the model with AMD hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Run the system distribution upgrade from within Ubuntu 12.04. Just be sure to set it to only recognize the LTS releases. There's no reason to do a clean install from USB.

Comment: Yes there is and even if not, it's a good idea to make sure there's a working live system available.